# The property of closed subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

We know that a set is **closed** if and only if every convergent sequence with elements in the set has a limit point in the set.

I am reading a paper, and the paper claims that the following is due to *S* is a closed subspace:

Suppose we know:

*S* is a closed constraints subspace. *K* is a matrix.

1. $K \in S$
2. $K(GK)^n \in S, \forall n$

then

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty K(GK)^n \in S$
(Note: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty K(GK)^n$ is a **convergent summation** and $(GK)^n$ is **convergent** **sequence**)

Why is this related to the condition that $S$ is a **closed** subspace?
(This is the sum of this sequence.)

> Paper title: A Characterization of Convex Problem in Decentralized Control

Comment: What paper are you reading (author(s), title, etc.)? What does the notation "$K(GK)^n$" mean? What is $S$ supposed to be a closed subspace of?

Comment: This paper is very complicated. I try to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: Not every question involving sets is about set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about some linear space. In this case, we know that the partial sums
$$P_m := \sum_{n=0}^{m} K(GK)^n$$
are in $S$, because they are just finite sums of elements in $S$. If the limit $P = \lim_{m \to \infty} P_m$ exists, we know that $P \in S$ since $S$ is closed.

However, I believe that there is some kind of convergence argument missing that tells you that $P_m$ is a convergent sequence.

Comment: So the point is the finite sums of elements in the closed subspace is still in this subspce. If this sum is convergent, then the infinite sum of elements in the closed subspace is still in this subspace?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.